# How to return to Django from an Angular form?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

In a Django 1.8 app I have a form that is posting using Angular.js. After the form has been submitted by Angular to Django Rest Framework I would like to move to another Django view. My question is **how to move to another Django view apart from using $windows.location.href?**

At the moment I'm using $windows.location.href but I would like Django(meaning not Javascript/Angular) to move to another page. Here's how I do it now - for brevity here's a small part of this form in my template:

```
<div ng-app="pacjent">
(...)
<div ng-controller="NewPatientCtrl">
(...)
    <form name="newPatientForm" ng-submit="newPatientForm.$valid && submitNewPatientForm()" ng-init="initialize('{{user.id}}')" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    (...)
    </form>
```

This form is posting all data to Django Rest Framework like this:

```
        function submitNewPatientForm(){
            /* it's prime goal is to submit name,surname, age & phone to createNewPatient API */
            $scope.setBusy = true;
            savePatient = $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost:8000/pacjent/api/createNewPatient/',
                        data: $scope.newPatient,
                    })
                    .then(function successCallback(response){

                        newPatient = response.data['id'];

                        createNewTherapyGroup();
                        url = patientDetailView + response.data.id + '/';
                        $window.location.href=url;  # I DON"T WANT TO USE THIS, but I don't know how!
                    }, function errorCallback(response){
                        if (response['data']['name'] && response['data']['surname']) {
                            $scope.newPatientForm.newPatientName.$setValidity("patientExists", false);
                            $scope.errors.newPatientName =response.data['name'][0];
            }

(...)
```

Is there a way to do it differently?

Comment: You should define state for each view. You have to call those state for transition. You may study on angular state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want django to control the redirect, don’t post the form using AJAX, just post it back to django with a regular form so that you can redirect the user to another view.

e.g.,

```
<form name="newPatientForm" method="POST" action=""> 
{% csrf_token %}
(...)
</form>
```

in your view:

```
def new_patient_form_submit(request):
    name = request.POST['. . .']
    . . .
    return redirect('another_view_name')
```

alternatively, you can have the REST endpoint return a success JSON response with the URL to redirect to so that you don’t have to hardcode it into your JS file:

```
           .then(function successCallback(response){
                    newPatient = response.data['id'];
                    var next = response.data['next']; // get the next URL to go to from the django REST endpoint
                    createNewTherapyGroup();
                    $window.location.href = next;  // redirect to the django-provided route
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think you mentioned the only 2 possibilities, there's isn't anything else... It's a good hint to return the response with the URL to redirect to - thanks!